# How to overlay 2 videos, one is main second one is overlaying it, and play sound simultaneously. using FFMPEG in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

as title say I'm trying to overlay 2 videos and play sound simultaneously. So far i managed to put 1 video over another using this command:

```
String[] command = {"-i", mainVideoPath, "-vf",
            "movie=" + overlayVideo + ", scale=300:-1[inner]; [in][inner]overlay=10:10[out]" ,combinedVideoOutput};
```

and this works but I have 3 problems here.
First, video is rotated by 90 degrees (overlay video), second Audio is played only from main video (I want to play sound from both videos simultaneously), and third overlay video is longer (for example: overlayVideo duration is 10 seconds and main video last 7 seconds) then mainVideo, so i want to final video last as long as mainVideo, as soon as mainVideo finish, overlayVideo should also stop (need to cut it prolly ?)

```
String[] command = {"-i", mainVideoPath, "-i", overlayVideo ,
            "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(256/256)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10" ,combinedVideoOutput};
```

Using this command i have 2 problems same as above except video is not rotated here.
I have to say that I'm not very familiar with ffmpeg commands. I was trying to figure it out from documentation [link to documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) but without any success.
I know that I'm missing some filters like -map merge or something but can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT1:**
This is logcat from second commad as asked

```
D/LISKO: ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
D/LISKO:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
D/LISKO:   libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
      libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
      libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
      libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
      libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
D/LISKO:   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
      libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
D/LISKO:   libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
      libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
D/LISKO: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/mainVideo.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : iso6
        minor_version   : 1
        compatible_brands: mp42iso6avc1isom
        creation_time   : 2020-08-03T13:20:11.000000Z
      Duration: 00:00:07.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1380 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 140 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2020-07-28T08:11:36.000000Z
        Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 81:256 DAR 9:16], 1264 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2020-07-28T08:11:36.000000Z
D/LISKO: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/overlayVideo.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: isommp42
        creation_time   : 2020-08-04T07:27:47.000000Z
        com.android.version: 10
      Duration: 00:00:11.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9993 kb/s
D/LISKO:     Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 9238 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 28.38 fps, 29.75 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 270
          creation_time   : 2020-08-04T07:27:47.000000Z
          handler_name    : VideoHandle
        Side data:
          displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
        Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2020-08-04T07:27:47.000000Z
          handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale2ref:ref (graph 0)
      Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale2ref:default (graph 0)
      overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
D/LISKO: [libx264 @ 0xee986100] using SAR=81/256
D/LISKO: [libx264 @ 0xee986100] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
    [libx264 @ 0xee986100] profile High, level 3.1
D/LISKO: [libx264 @ 0xee986100] 264 - core 152 r2851M ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
D/LISKO: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/outputVideo.mp4':
D/LISKO:   Metadata:
        major_brand     : iso6
D/LISKO:     minor_version   : 1
D/LISKO:     compatible_brands: mp42iso6avc1isom
D/LISKO:     encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 81:256 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
D/LISKO:     Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
D/LISKO:     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2020-07-28T08:11:36.000000Z
D/LISKO:       encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
D/LISKO: frame=   26 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.09 bitrate=   4.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.185x    
D/LISKO: frame=   41 fps= 41 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.58 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.574x    
D/LISKO: frame=   49 fps= 32 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.92 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.613x    
D/LISKO: frame=   59 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.97 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.974x    
D/LISKO: frame=   75 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.97 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.762x
```

**EDIT2:**
After adding "-shortest" to command i managed to cut overlay  video to be the same length as main video (because overlay video is always longer then mainVideo, "-shortest" take short one duration. So now, command looks like this:

```
    String[] command = {"-i", mainVideoPath, "-i", overlayVideo ,"-filter_complex", 
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(256/256)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10", "-shortest", combinedVideoOutput};
```

Rotation is good so only need to merge their audios. For now, only mainVideo audio is playing, overlay video audio isn't

**EDIT 3:**

```
   String[] command = {"-i", mainVideoPath, "-i", overlayVideo ,
            "-strict", "experimental",
            "-filter_complex",
            "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(256/256)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];" +
                    "[base][wm]overlay=10:10; " +
                    "pan=stereo|c0=2*c0|c1=3*c0[a0];[1:a]pan=stereo|c0=1*c0|c1=4*c0[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2",
            "-shortest" ,combinedVideoOutput};
```

With this command i managed to overlay videos, and play sound from both of them, rotation is good, but -shortest doesn't work now. Only existing problem now is to make them to last as shorter one (mainVideo is always shorter)???

**EDIT 4:**

This is finally working command

```
        String[] command = {"-i", mainVideoPath, "-i", overlayVideo,
            "-filter_complex",
            "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(256/256)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];" +
                    "[base][wm]overlay=10:10:shortest=1;" +
                    "pan=stereo|c0=2*c0|c1=3*c0[a0];[1:a]pan=stereo|c0=1*c0|c1=4*c0[a1];" +
                    "[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2",
            combinedVideoOutput};
```

Thanks

Comment: This is purely a ffmpeg usage issue, so the android stuff is in the way. Show the complete log from command #2.

Comment: @llogan i edited question and posted complete log from command 2 . But i don't know why is that needed here ? Command 2 is working fine but with 3 problems described above :) . Those msgs are from ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler callback (onProgress and onSuccess)

Comment: Sorry for command 2 there are 2 issues not 3, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `shortest` option in the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
overlay=10:10:shortest=1
```

Comment: Also, remove `-strict experimental`. That's old junk from more than 5 years ago.

Comment: TY GOD. After 2 days of struggling with ffmpeg commands i made it. IIogan thanks for help :) that was the missing part of command

Comment: How do i increase second video size its bit smaller @llogan

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure but probabbly by increasing this number
(256/256)
Can't remember was long ago :/